# Backbone User Model with multiple update paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I have built a simple user model in Backbone

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

   var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot: '/api/user',
      idAttribute: '_id',
      defaults: {
         userName: '',
         password: ''
         personalDetails: {
         title: '',
         name: {
           firstName: '',
           lastName: ''
         },
         gender: '',
         dob: ''
       }
    }
 });

 return UserModel;
});
```

Calling `save()` on the model will issue a PUT request to `/api/user/:id` which is fine.

However, in the front end I want 3 forms - `updatePersonalDetails`, `updateUserName`, `updatePassword`.

With my current implementation these will all use the same model and all `save()` to the same endpoint `/api/user/:id`. My problem is that I wont know which form the user posted.

Whats the best solution to this issue whilst still conforming to RESTful standards? Having 3 separate Models - `UserDetailsModel`, `UserPasswordModel` etc? Or to just do a bulk UPDATE on the whole model regardless of which form the user posted.

Comment: Interesting question, this is one of my personal beefs with REST as it's often presented: we're basically giving access to database inserts, updates and deletes through a HTTP interface.

Comment: @mtsr, this is a bad overall look on REST APIs. You should always require the user to be logged in, sending an `401 Unauthorized` if it's not, and then check their permissions, sending an `403 Forbidden` if it's the case.

Comment: @redeye, I think you don't need to "know" what form has been sent in the model. I believe that the best thing you be to call different methods of your model which will trigger the save differently, only sending the relevant data. I'm not sure, but I believe this is REST compliant.

Comment: @gustavohenke Sure, you still secure your REST API, but wouldn't it be nice to have a finer grained filter than updates on specific models, model instances or custom field checking? E.g. a more command like interface, where you don't send a PUT to /user/1 but /user/1/changeAddress?

Comment: @mtsr, Actually, that's what I meant :P

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It seems I can issue a PATCH request. e.g. this.model.save(attr, {PATCH: true}); This will only send the supplied attr to the server. This poses another question - I will need form validation on the server, so I still require some knowledge of which form the user has posted. I want to avoid sniffing the req.body on the server

Comment: @gustavohenke From what I gather, that's not considered fully RESTful, though.

Comment: @gustavohenke I believe patch is part of RESTful conventions? Having /api/user/:id/changeAddress isnt RESTful though? Also Backbone wont fire off a PUT request to /api/user/:id/changeAddress out of the box. I think provided patch works and the model stays synced with the server, then i'm happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allot been discussed regarding model separation vs model BULK in the question comments, I have nothing to add there.

Regarding your need to understand the UPDATE request form source,  you can use query string parameters:

Just POST /api/user/1?form=my_special_form

In backbone you just need to save the model with url option

```
model.save({}, {
  url: model.url() + "?form=my_special_form"
});
```